# caching static files for ruby on rails application using nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx, static-files

I have been trying for some time to serve & cache static files for my rails app using nginx. the rails app server runs mongrel_cluster and is deployed on a different host than that of nginx.

following many of the available discussions I tried the following

```
server {

     listen       80;

     server_name  www.myappserver.com;



     ssl on;

     root /var/apps/myapp/current/public;



     location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ {

            root /var/apps/myapp/current;

            expires 10y;

                                                    }



     location / {

                    proxy_pass http://myapp_upstream;

                }

                  }
```

But nginx fails to find the images and to load the css and js files. Can anyone help me out here?

My aim is to configure nginx in such a way that it caches the static files till expiry.

Please suggest me some way to achieve this or am I missing any point here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there. I believe Ezra here @ Engine Yard wrote a blog post on this years ago. All of this works out of the box @ EY, so that is one way to utilize his expertise. :-)